# how to share a theme and make it downloadable via package control

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, package-control

I made a Vibrant theme which inclludes markdown and restructured text syntax highlighting in sublime text and would like to share it via package control. Is there a way to do that so that it will be accessible and installable

Comment: You can see [submitting a Package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package) in official *package-control* docs.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have already hosted your theme on GitHub or Bitbucket:

1. Fork the [package control channel](https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel)
2. Add your theme to the matching repository file (see below)
3. Submit pull request

If your theme is called "My Theme" , you would add this to `repository/m.json`. Make sure you to put your theme at the right position, the list is meant to be alphabetized. Also make sure your JSON is valid before submitting.

One last word on the `tags` value, as it was only introduced with Package Control 3.0. New packages need to tagged releases in your repository, so keep this set `true`. (Old packages could be organized by timestamp instead.)

More on [Submitting a Package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package) in the official documentation.

Comment: You should add a link to the complete docs: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package